# Spring Roo "perform" hangs

Tags: java, macos, spring, maven, spring-roo

I'm having trouble getting Roo to generate the necessary eclipse configuration file.  Whenever I execute `perform eclipse` (or any other `perform` command) the shell hangs without error and I'm forced to ^C to kill it.  I have reviewed the logs and there are no messages present, error or otherwise.  I did some Googling and came across [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?87583-roo-hangs-on-quot-perform-quot-commands) which describes *exactly* the problem I'm having.

However, the OP's solution was that Maven was incorrectly installed.  I'm running OSX 10.8 which has maven 3.0 installed by default.  On the off chance there was a compatibility issue, I upgraded to 3.1 with the same results. When I execute `mvn` from the command line outside of Roo, maven seems to execute normally but spits out the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.139s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 11 10:33:25 PDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Which seems to indicate that maven is functioning properly, albeit without the necessary configurations in the pom file.  I'm a bit a rookie with maven so I'm not exactly sure what it's supposed to say there when I haven't given it a target.  Obviously there's still a chance it's incorrectly installed, I'm just not sure what I should be looking for to prove that one way or another. Any thoughts?

**Update** I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` per @CodeChimp's suggestion and it seems to have worked properly.  It downloaded a bunch of jar files that definitely look like logical dependencies and ended with `BUILD SUCCESS`. I'm at a loss for why that worked when the other didn't.

Comment: can you try doing a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the command line?  This is what the Roo shell is doing.  Also, are you running Roo from within Eclipse directly, using the plugin, or are you running the Roo Shell from the command line?

Comment: @CodeChimp Definitely, I'll get back to you on what happens.  As to your other question, I'm running it from the command line Roo Shell.  I haven't actually fired up eclipse for this project yet.

Comment: @CodeChimp see my update.  That seems to have worked although I'm not sure what the difference was...

Comment: The next thing I would try would be to turn on debug mode in the roo shell.  I think this is accomplished by running the following command in the roo shell: `development mode --enabled true`

Comment: @CodeChimp Well, now it seems to work although I can't figure out what's different.  Initially this morning, I ran `roo` and it behaved like there was no project setup.  Then, I ran it again and `perform eclipse` worked perfectly...bizarre...

Comment: I had to adjust the JVM params for the heap space to get roo to stop hanging on me.  You can add them under `/bin/roo.sh` or `/bin/roo.bat`

Comment: @rwyland ahhhh thats an excellent idea...Disappointed that hadn't ocurred to me! Let me try that and get back to you